# C# Extending all [Flag] enums?

Tags: c#

```
public static bool Get(this EventFlags flags, EventFlags flag)
{
    return ((flags & flag) != 0);
}

public static void Set(this EventFlags flags, EventFlags flag, bool value)
{
    if (value)
        flags |= flag;
    else
        flags &= ~flag;
}
```

basically I want to do that for any [Flag] enum, for instance

```
[Flags]
public enum FlagEn
{
   None = 0x0000,
   UseSkill = 0x0001
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you really *want* is a generic method with an enum constraint. However, C# doesn't allow that.

Fortunately, the CLR *does* allow it, and with a little hackery you can use a library to get goodness like this - although I should point out that your `Set` method currently doesn't actually do anything - you should really make it *return* the value after computing it.

I have a library for precisely this sort of thing which you might want to look at: [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/).  Note that even with the hackery, the constraint can't enforce at *compile* time that you're actually calling it on a flags enum and not some other enum. (I do provide execution-time checking though.)

For what you're after, I suggest you look at the [`Flags`](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/source/browse/trunk/UnconstrainedMelody/Flags.cs) class - in particular the `Or`, `HasAny` and `HasAll` methods.

Comment: Or use the new Enum methods of .NET 4 (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx)... Nevertheless I like the weirdness that happens in Unconstrained Melody :)

Comment: @Florian: My methods don't involve boxing, either :) (There's an understandable reluctance to introduce another dependency when the framework provides what you need though...)

Comment: "A user of this method should be aware that the current implementation is painfully slow, approximately 1000 times slower than manually inlining the code that the method is defined to expand into, and therefore use in performance critical code is not recommended. "?

Comment: Maybe they should have used Jons implementation :) Are there any benchmarks available Jon?

Comment: @Florian: I certainly haven't benchmarked it, no. Feel free to :)

Comment: I will see if I can find some spare minutes :)

Comment: @Florian: Of course, one nice thing about Unconstrained Melody being open source is that if we can find an obvious optimization, we can implement it :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, as there is no such thing as a `FlagEnum`, only an `enum` with the `Flag` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static bool Get(this Enum theEnum, Enum flag)
    {
        var flagsAttributes = theEnum.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FlagsAttribute), false);
        if (flagsAttributes.Length == 0)
            return false; // not a [Flags] enum

        return theEnum.HasFlag(flag);
    }
}
```

You could consider returning a `bool?` instead and return `null` when the `enum` doesn't have the `[Flags]` attribute.